# Variable interpolation inside nested quotations in React JSX

Tags: variables, nested, jsx, interpolation, quotations

I am new in react, don't know how to display photo inside nested quotations, I know the usages of
Variable interpolation inside single quote: `{assets/images/categories/${photo}}` but don't know how to make dynamic cat-2.jpg

```html
const AllItems = ({ post: { id, name, type, photo } }) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div className="product__discount__item">
        <div
          className="product__discount__item__pic set-bg"
          style={{
              backgroundImage: "url('assets/images/categories/cat-2.jpg')"
          }}
        >
          <div className="product__discount__percent">-20%</div>
        </div>
        <div className="product__discount__item__text">
          <span>{name}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved using variable

```html
const AllItems = ({ post: { id, name, type, photo } }) => {
  const imgPath = `assets/images/categories/${photo}`;
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
      <div className="product__discount__item">
        <div
          className="product__discount__item__pic set-bg"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${imgPath})`
          }}
        >
          <div className="product__discount__percent">-20%</div>
        </div>
        <div className="product__discount__item__text">
          <span>{name}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```